# Partial Differentiation

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I was just wondering whether anyone could help me with this question- I need to differentiate

$$
y_t = p - \left(\frac{a}{a_2 + c}\right)(m_0 +by_t + v_t) + \left(\frac{a}{a_2+c}\right) a_1 +u_t
$$

wrt $a_1$ and $a_2$. ($a$ is a constant). I haven't done partial differentiation for a few years! Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! (t is supposed to be subscript, it's not a value) I assume I need to use the product rule somewhere...

Comment: @thomas: Thanks for taking the time to improved the formatting. I think you inadvertently changed the meaning of the equation; I've changed it to be equivalent to the original. Nathan, please check whether this is what you meant.

Comment: I also turned the $t$ into a subscript, as you apparently intended. You can learn how to do this yourself by looking at the $\TeX$ code, either by clicking on the edit link or by right-clicking on the formula and selecting "Show Math As:TeX Commands".

Comment: Yes this is what I meant thanks!

Comment: You edited back to what thomas had written and then wrote that what I did was what you meant -- that's contradictory. Note that the present version corresponds to thomas' version and not to what you had originally, where the division was only by $a_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you just regard whichever you are not differentiating by as a constant.  So $$\frac{\partial y_t}{\partial a_1} = \left(\frac{a}{a_2+c}\right)\\\frac{\partial y_t}{\partial a_2} = -\left(\frac{-a}{(a_2 + c)^2}\right)(m_0 +by_t + v_t) + \left(\frac{-a}{(a_2+c)^2}\right) a_1 = \left(\frac{a}{(a_2 + c)^2}\right)(m_0 +by_t + v_t-a_1)$$

Comment: Thanks! I actually realised that I made a bit of a mistake though, I didn;t get all of the yt terms over to one side.

My new equation is:


$$
y_t = \left(\frac{a_2 + c}{a_2 + ab + c}\right)(p + u_t) + \left(\frac{a}{a_2+ ab + c}\right) (a_1 - m_0 - v_t)
$$

with a2 as a numerator, how would I do this for a2)?

Thanks

Comment: You use the quotient rule, so $\frac \partial{\partial a_2} \left(\frac{a_2 + c}{a_2 + ab + c}\right)=\frac {(a_2+ab+c)-(a_2+c)}{(a_2+ab+c)^2}$